# printing a page using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to print using jquery. I have the following in my js file

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'mydiv', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write($(elem).html());
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
```

and in my view:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" />
```

The popup is working correctly but it is printing empty doc. What am I doing Wrong

Comment: I think the new window does not have access the content of #mydiv. Try passing the content to the function

Comment: I have the contents in the function. 'elem' has already the content.